# How to calculate the density of a polycrystalline sample?

Tags: crystals, density

I'm trying to figure out the density (g/cm^3) of La2CuO4. I know that the mass is 405.355 g/mol; what do I have to do to calculate the volume? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need the crystal structure and unit cell dimensions to obtain the molar volume.  Being polycrystalline rather than single crystal means your actual sample is probably slightly less dense than you will calculate.  A quick Google search on 'unit cell LaCuO2' brought up a paper by Bob Cava in J. Mater. Res. 9(2) 314-317 (1993) with a table of the structure of different related materials under different oxidation conditions.  It includes LaCuO2.

Comment: That doesn't seem relevant to La2CuO4 but maybe I am missing something. You can Google for "unit cell La2CuO4" and there is a book "Superconductivity" by Poole et al that includes the information you are looking for on page 701-704, or so it seems.

Comment: @Floris - thanks for catching that.  I must have misread the subscript - La2CuO4 is much easier to find than La2CuO2 so I assumed (bad of me) they were seeking the harder one. Bhattacharya's book on superconductors indicates a=0.379 and c=1.323 nm; not sure how that compares with Poole's.

Answer (score 0):

A mole is a specific number of objects (in this case, molecules) and therefore tells you exactly nothing about density. It does allow you to calculate the mass of a single molecule.

You cannot figure out the density unless you know the crystalline structure that your molecule takes on -- if in fact it does so -- as well as the lattice spacings between molecules.

Answer (score 0):

You measure the volume, and hence the density, using a [pycnometer bottle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_density#Pycnometer).

You weigh the bottle, then fill it with the fluid of your choice (choose one that wets your powder easily) and weight it again. The different in weight divided by the density of the fluid gives you the bottle volume.

Now clean, dry and reweigh your bottle. Add your powder and reweight to get the powder weight. Now fill with fluid and reweigh to get the fluid weight. Divide by the density, subtract from the volume you calculated above and now you have the volume of your powder.

Comment: True, but technically this does not "calculate" the density so much as measure it. :-)